# Python loop optimization

Tags: python, dictionary

I am currently working with a file with more than 2 million lines. I've separated the lines into lists of elements (ex: `[a,b,c,d]` = 1 line, words separated).

I'm trying to use the following code to go through all the lines:

```
for a in aud:
    for esps in final:
        if a[0] in final[esps]:
            a[0] = esps
```

In the first for loop I'm referring to the 2 million+ lines. In the second for loop it goes through a dictionary with 2010 keys, each key with probably at least 50 corresponding values. I want to find the `a[0]` element in the lines that are equal to the values in the dictionary. If they match, I change the `a[0]` element in the selected line to the value of the key of the dictionary.

The problem is that this code takes ages to run and I don't understand much (nothing) about optimization and how to run this much faster.
I would thank a lot if anyone could tell me how to do something like this faster.

Comment: hmm, are you limited to just one computer? I think you can use several workers to do that. Even with one computer, you can also create multiple workers with a multicore CPU

Comment: It is a bit hard to undestand your actual problem given this description with none example data.  Are all the 50 keys in each of the "final" dictionary strings?

Comment: Won't this have a side effect of mutating an object while iterating over it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you have "big" things to run through, like this, the key to get things going fast is to "reduce algorithmic complexity" - that is, avoid any operations that depend on the size of either data set if possible.

In the example you gave, you perform, for each of your millions of lines a 50 x 2000 linear search - that is a lot! The problem being that if each of your `final[esps]` is a list, Python performs a linear search in these 50 values - with the operator `in`.

Since you mention you are reading your values from a file, I have to assume that both a[0] and the elements in the lines of `final` are strings - but this would also work for numbers.

A first, very simple optimization, is to simply change your `final` dictionary rows from lists into `set`s - with a `set` the match from the `in` operator changes from being linear to be in constant time (from O(m) to O(1) ) - so, you basically cut your search time by a factor of 50 if before running the code in your example you do:

```
for key in final:
   final[key] = set(final[key])
```

But you are still performing a linear search in each of the 2010 keys of `final`. The way to change that into a constant search is to create a reversed dictionary - in which each of the 50 values in a row of `final` point to the key `esp` instead. Then you just use a[0] as the key in this reversed dictionary - and you are replacing a linear search in 100000 items (2000 x 50) for a search in constant time in a dictionary;

That is easy to accomplish - just change your code to:

```
rfinal = {}
for esp, values in final.items():
   for value in values:
       rfinal[value] = esp


for a in aud:
    if a[0] in rfinal:
       a[0] = rfinal[a[0]]
    else:
       # code for when there is no match for a[0]
       ...
```

Comment: This example just changed everything. From more than 1 hour without finishing...to mere seconds. This helped a lot! With my work and towards understanding how I can optimize code in the future. Thank you 2 million+ times ahah!

Comment: It is just roughly 100.000 times faster in this case :-)  -
If it worked, please remember to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: A good place to practisize this kind of optimization problems is https://projecteuler.net/